# Netcat throws a "getnameinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution" error

Tags: ubuntu, netcat, ubuntu-20.04

When I run the following command: `nc -luvp 9090`, I get the error: `getnameinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution`

I've scanned the internet in search of an answer, but none of them were valid:

- https://github.com/bonzini/netcat/issues/2: not answered
- https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/fa8l7s/issue_running_netcat_lvp/: not answered

I found this link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/504963/how-to-solve-a-temporary-failure-in-name-resolution-error
And tried the most upvoted answer. My results:

[image: netcat_name_resolution_error]

**I'm using NordVPN, which uses its own DNS servers. But I tried disabling it completely, and I get the same exact result. I'm afraid it messed up with my DNS config file and/or firewall rules.**

I'm kinda new to Linux and feel a bit lost.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem could be with the DNS resolver. Try updating the **namespace** in `/etc/resolv.conf` as follows.

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: To implement this: Open the command line and type `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`. At the editor, after doing what's above, use `CTRL` + `O` to save and  `CTRL` + `X` to exit. Reboot at the end

Comment: @VascoCansadoCarvalho I feel we can simply do `sudo gedit` instead of nano, it's GUI so I feel it's better

Answer (score 7):

You seem to be using `systemd-resolved` for your DNS resolver, which seems unable to resolve `0.0.0.0`:

```
$ resolvectl query 0.0.0.0
0.0.0.0: resolve call failed: No appropriate name servers or networks for name found

$ host 0.0.0.0 127.0.0.53
Using domain server:
Name: 127.0.0.53
Address: 127.0.0.53#53
Aliases:

Host 0.0.0.0.in-addr.arpa not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
```

This is the address `netcat` is trying to resolve and fails (in my tests at least). One solution is to add a static association by adding the following line in `/etc/hosts`:

```
0.0.0.0    localhost
```

`netcat` should not abort for such a harmless DNS failure (it works when using the `-n` switch or removing the `-v` switch) and `systemd-resolved` should probably not send `SERVFAIL` when resolving `0.0.0.0`.